# Whats event for bot disconnect

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, nextcord

I need to close database connection when bot stopped (example - Cntrl+C)

My code:

```
class BotEvents(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot : Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready (self) -> None:
        await database.initialize_database(database = config.database.database)

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_disconnect(self) -> None: # not working
        await database.close_connection()`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What's the question? Does something not work? If so, any errors? What do you expect?

Comment: thats just not call -  on_disconnect

Comment: Have you checked it e.g. with a print? Also your code doesn't show the setup coroutine which is required for the cog to be initialized.

Comment: other events works fine.
yeah i cheked with print

Answer (score 1):

When you control-C, no cleanup can occur and the program is stopped immediately.

However, you can make a signal handler to catch the signal and then do the cleanup.

```py
import signal

async def close_bot():
    await database.close_connection()
    await bot.close()
    exit(0)

def terminate_handler(signal, frame):
    await asyncio.get_event_loop().run(close_bot())

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, terminate_handler)
```